# agregar un paginado a cada hoja de un PDF en django 2.7 con reportlab 3.5

Tags: python, django, pdf, django-views, reportlab

tengo el siguiente codigo
un clase en el views de Django

class GeneratePDFView(View):

```
def page_number(self, canvas, doc):
    # Obtén el número actual de la página y el total de páginas
    page_number = canvas.getPageNumber()
    total_pages = len(doc.pages)
    
    # Define la cadena de texto de la paginación
    page_text = f'Página {page_number} de {total_pages}'
    
    # Configura la fuente y el tamaño
    canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 9)
    
    # Dibuja el texto en la esquina superior derecha
    canvas.drawRightString(doc.pagesize[0] - 20, doc.pagesize[1] - 20, page_text)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Obtain data of models, audit, itinerary and report_finding, create pdf
    @author: Gerson Merchan <gmerchan@campus.udes.edu.co>
    @last modified: 01/11/2023
    """
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
    pk2 = self.kwargs.get('pk2', None)
    audit = Audit.objects.get(id=pk)
    itinerary = Itinerary.objects.get(id=pk2)
    report_findings = ReportFindings.objects.filter(itinerary_id=pk2)
    report_finding = ReportFindings.objects.get(itinerary_id=pk2)

    #itinerary data
    date_init = itinerary.date_init
    date_end = itinerary.date_end
    date_init_formatted = date_init.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    date_end_formatted = date_end.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    hour_init = itinerary.hour_init
    hour_end = itinerary.hour_end
    hour_init_formatted = hour_init.strftime('%H:%M')
    hour_end_formatted = hour_end.strftime('%H:%M')
    
    #report_findind  data
    date_init = report_finding.date_init
    date_end = report_finding.date_end
    date_init_report = date_init.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    date_end_report = date_end.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    hour_init = report_finding.hour_init
    hour_end = report_finding.hour_end
    hour_init_report = hour_init.strftime('%H:%M')
    hour_end_report = hour_end.strftime('%H:%M')
    
    audited_names = [str(user) for user in itinerary.audited.all()]
    formatted_names = ', '.join(audited_names)
    
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'inline; filename="informe_hallazgos.pdf"'
    buffer = BytesIO()
    # doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=legal, leftMargin=0.9 * inch, rightMargin=0.9 * inch, topMargin=0.5 * inch, bottomMargin=0.2 * inch)
    doc = SimpleDocTemplate(buffer, pagesize=legal, leftMargin=0.9 * inch, rightMargin=0.9 * inch, topMargin=0.5 * inch, bottomMargin=0.2 * inch, onPage=self.page_number)

    doc.title = "Informe de Hallazgos"
    elements = []
    styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
    #paragraph styles 
    centered_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CenteredStyle', alignment=1)
    left_style = ParagraphStyle(name='LeftStyle', alignment=0, spaceBefore=0)
    right_style = ParagraphStyle(name='RightStyle', alignment=0, spaceBefore=0)
    #title styles
    centered_heading_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CenteredHeading1',  parent=styles['Heading1'],alignment=1)
    left_heading_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CenteredHeading1',  parent=styles['Heading1'],alignment=0)
    # header
    left_image_path = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], 'app/img/udes_big.png')
    right_image_path = os.path.join(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0], 'app/img/logo_sgc_vaf.png')
    left_image = Image(left_image_path)
    right_image = Image(right_image_path)
    left_image.drawHeight = 50
    left_image.drawWidth = 150
    right_image.drawHeight = 50
    right_image.drawWidth = 150
    title = Paragraph("INFORME DE HALLAZGOS DE AUDITORÍA", centered_heading_style)
    # elements.append(Spacer(1, 20))
    font_size=10
    title_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CustomStyle', alignment=1, textColor=colors.gray, fontSize=font_size)
    
    image_table_data = [[left_image, "", right_image]]
    col_widths = [doc.width / 2, doc.width / 10, doc.width / 2]
    image_table = Table(image_table_data, colWidths=col_widths)
    image_table.setStyle([('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, 0), 'LEFT'),
                          ('ALIGN', (2, 0), (2, 0), 'RIGHT'),
                          ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP')]
                         )
    header =Paragraph("<b>Quality App System</b>", title_style)
    elements.append(header)
    elements.append(Spacer(1, 10))
    elements.append(image_table)
    elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
    elements.append(title)
    for finding in report_findings:
        content = []
        elements.append(HRFlowable(width="100%", thickness=1, spaceAfter=12))
        content.append(Paragraph(f'{audit.id}-{audit.name}', centered_style))
        content.append(Paragraph(f'{date_init_formatted} {hour_init_formatted} Hrs - {date_end_formatted} {hour_end_formatted} Hrs', centered_style))
        elements.extend(content)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        
        # table1 data info itineary 
        table_data = [
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Proceso: </b> {itinerary.process}', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Campus: </b>{itinerary.site}', right_style)],
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Fecha-Hora Inicio: </b>{date_init_report} {hour_init_report} Hrs ', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Auditor lider: </b>{itinerary.auditor_leader}', right_style)],
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Fecha-Hora Fin: </b>{date_end_report} {hour_end_report} Hrs ', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Auditados: </b>{formatted_names}', right_style)],
        ]
        col_widths = [doc.width / 2 - inch * 0.5, doc.width / 2 + inch] 
        table = Table(table_data, colWidths=col_widths)
        table_style = TableStyle([
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (1, -1), 'RIGHT'),
        ])
        table.setStyle(table_style)
        elements.append(table)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        
        elements.append(HRFlowable(width="100%", thickness=1, spaceAfter=12))
        elements.append(Paragraph(f'Listado de Hallazgos', centered_heading_style))
        
        file_id=[]
        questions = []
        standards = []
        numerals = []
        report_findings_ids = [rf.id for rf in report_findings]
        first_report_findings_id = report_findings_ids[0]
        if report_findings:
            findings = Findings.objects.filter(report_findings_id=first_report_findings_id)
            if findings:
                file_id = [finding.file_id for finding in findings]
                evidence = [finding.evidence for finding in findings]
                conforming = [finding.conforming for finding in findings]
                recomendations = [finding.recomendations for finding in findings]
                question_ids = findings.values_list('question_id', flat=True)
                questions = QuestionVerificationList.objects.filter(id__in=question_ids)
                if questions:
                    standards = [str(question.standard) if question.standard else '' for question in questions]
                    numerals = [str(question.numeral_quality) if question.numeral_quality else '' for question in questions]
                    question = [question.question for question in questions]
        preguntas = []
        for i in range(len(questions)):
            pregunta = {
                'file_id': findings[i].file_id,
                'standard': standards[i],
                'numeral_quality': numerals[i],
                'question': question[i],
                'conforming': findings[i].conforming,
                'evidence': findings[i].evidence,
                'recomendations': findings[i].recomendations,
            }
            preguntas.append(pregunta)
        
        #table2 findings
        font_size = 8
        custom_style = ParagraphStyle(name='CustomStyle', alignment=1, textColor=colors.black, fontSize=font_size)
        header_style = ParagraphStyle(name='HeaderStyle', alignment=1, textColor=colors.white, fontSize=font_size)
        table_data2 = [
        ]
        header_data = ['ID Archivo', 'Norma', 'Numeral', 'Pregunta', 'Conforme', 'Evidencia', 'Recomendaciones']
        table_data2.append([Paragraph(header, header_style) for header in header_data])
        col_widths2 = [doc.width * 0.09, doc.width * 0.1, doc.width * 0.1, doc.width * 0.25, doc.width * 0.11, doc.width * 0.2, doc.width * 0.2]
        for pregunta in preguntas:
            if pregunta['file_id'] is None:
                file_id_value = "-"
            else:
                file_id_value = str(pregunta['file_id'])
                
            if pregunta['conforming'] == 0:
                conforming_value = "Conforme"
            elif pregunta['conforming'] == 1:
                conforming_value = "No Conforme"
            else:
                conforming_value = "Observaciones"
            row_data = [
                Paragraph(file_id_value, custom_style),
                Paragraph(pregunta['standard'], custom_style),
                Paragraph(pregunta['numeral_quality'], custom_style),
                Paragraph(pregunta['question'], custom_style),
                Paragraph(conforming_value, custom_style),
                Paragraph(pregunta['evidence'], custom_style),
                Paragraph(pregunta['recomendations'], custom_style)
            ]
            table_data2.append(row_data)
        table2 = Table(table_data2, colWidths=col_widths2)
        table_style2 = TableStyle([
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.grey),
            ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, 0), colors.whitesmoke),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 'Helvetica-Bold'),
            ('BOTTOMPADDING', (0, 0), (-1, 0), 12),
            ('BACKGROUND', (0, 1), (-1, -1), colors.whitesmoke),
            ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'MIDDLE'),
            ('GRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
            ('LINEBEFORE', (0, 0), (0, -1), 1, colors.black),
            ('LINEAFTER', (-1, 0), (-1, -1), 1, colors.black),
        ])
        table2.setStyle(table_style2)
        elements.append(table2)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        
        elements.append(HRFlowable(width="100%", thickness=1, spaceAfter=12))
        elements.append(Paragraph(f'Detalles de Ejecucion de la Auditoria', left_heading_style))

        # table3 data info itineary 
        table_data3 = [
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Fecha Inicio: </b> {date_init_report}', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Hora Inicio: </b> {hour_init_report} Hrs ', left_style), Paragraph(f'', right_style)],
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Fecha Fin: </b> {date_init_report}', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Hora Fin: </b> {hour_init_report} Hrs ', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Horas Auditadas: </b> {report_finding.hours_audited}', left_style)],
        ]
        col_widths3 = [doc.width / 3] * 3
        table3 = Table(table_data3, colWidths=col_widths3)
        table_style3 = TableStyle([
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (1, -1), 'CENTER'),
            ('ALIGN', (2, 0), (2, -1), 'RIGHT'),
        ])
        table3.setStyle(table_style3)
        elements.append(table3)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        
        # table4 data info itineary
        table_data4 = [
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Fortalezas: </b><br/>{report_finding.strengths}', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Debilidades: </b><br/>{report_finding.weaknesses}', right_style)],
            [Paragraph(f'<b>Conclusiones: </b><br/>{report_finding.conclusions}', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>No conformidades detectadas: </b><br/>{report_finding.detected_nonconforms}', right_style)],
        ]
        table_data4.extend([["", ""]])
        table_data4.extend([["", ""]])
        table_data4.append([Paragraph(f'<b>Firma Auditor: __________________________</b><br/>', left_style), Paragraph(f'<b>Firma Auditado: __________________________</b><br/>', left_style)])
        col_widths4 = [doc.width/2] * 2
        table4 = Table(table_data4, colWidths=col_widths4)
        table_style4 = TableStyle([
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (0, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('ALIGN', (1, 0), (1, -1), 'LEFT'),
            ('VALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'TOP'),
            ('LEFTPADDING', (0, 0), (0, -1), 1),
            ('RIGHTPADDING', (1, 0), (1, -1), 0),
            # ('GRID', (0, -1), (-1, -1), 0, colors.black)
        ])

        table4.setStyle(table_style4)
        elements.append(table4)
        elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
    doc.build(elements)
    buffer.seek(0)
    response.write(buffer.read())
    buffer.close()
    return response
```

la cual me genera bien el pdf pero necesito agregarle en la esquina superior derecha, la paginación
Es decir "Pagina 1 de 3", en la siguiente pagina "Pagina 2 de 3" y así...
esa es la manera en que tengo mas limpio el codigo, he intentado por varios días de diferentes maneras y no he podido
Gracias al que me pueda colaborar

necesito agregarle en la esquina superior derecha, la paginación
Es decir "Pagina 1 de 3", en la siguiente pagina "Pagina 2 de 3" y así...
esa es la manera en que tengo mas limpio el codigo, he intentado por varios días de diferentes maneras y no he podido
Gracias al que me pueda colaborar

Comment: Puedes usar un subclase como aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/59882495/2699806

Answer (score 0):

ya se pudo
se agregó el siguiente código al final de la clase

```
table4.setStyle(table_style4)
            elements.append(table4)
            elements.append(Spacer(1, 30))
        doc.build(elements, onFirstPage=lambda canvas, doc: self.encabezado_pie_pagina(canvas, doc, elements),
                  onLaterPages=lambda canvas, doc: self.encabezado_pie_pagina(canvas, doc, elements))
        buffer.seek(0)
        response.write(buffer.read())
        buffer.close()
        return response

    
    def encabezado_pie_pagina(self, canvas, doc, elements):
        
        canvas.saveState()
        canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 9)
        canvas.drawRightString(doc.width, inch * 0.5, f"Página {doc.page}")
        canvas.restoreState()
```